# Any language pack not working in frontend in magento

Tags: magento

I have installed de_DE lang pack using

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/locale-mage-community-de-de.html

Than i have changed language German for particular store in locale but no effect in frontend.

I have already flushed cache, index management.If i change any other locale pack its also not working.

I have also shown store switcher in front-end with

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_switcher') ?>
```

and it's also working but can't change language in frontend as per csv.

Comment: Check if the locale of the store is overwritten on another scope, e.g. Store View.